# Which version of saxon am I running

Tags: version, xquery, saxon

Simple question!

How can I find out which version of Saxon I am running? I have the "sazon9he.jar" file but I can't seem to figure out the exact version (i.e is it 9.7 or 9.6...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer only minutes after posting the question:

Simply run:
`java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Version`

Comment: or run `net.sf.saxon.Version` for more complete info